# Type - Decode XML in go

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, go

I have the following XML which I cannot decode .

```
     <pic:pictures><pic:picture><pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/lYcAAOxyeglTbII~/80"/>
<pic:link rel="preview" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/lYcAAOxyeglTbII~/81"/>
<pic:link rel="big" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/lYcAAOxyeglTbII~/79"/>
<pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/lYcAAOxyeglTbII~/78"/>
<pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/lYcAAOxyeglTbII~/77"/></pic:picture>

<pic:picture><pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/xl8AAOxyuR5TbIIu/80"/><pic:link rel="preview" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/xl8AAOxyuR5TbIIu/81"/><pic:link rel="big" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/xl8AAOxyuR5TbIIu/79"/><pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/xl8AAOxyuR5TbIIu/78"/><pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/xl8AAOxyuR5TbIIu/77"/></pic:picture>
 <pic:picture>
<pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/DjEAAOxy9X5TbII2/80"/>
<pic:link rel="preview" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/DjEAAOxy9X5TbII2/81"/>
<pic:link rel="big" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/DjEAAOxy9X5TbII2/79"/>
<pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/DjEAAOxy9X5TbII2/78"/>
<pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/DjEAAOxy9X5TbII2/77"/></pic:picture>

    <pic:picture>
   <pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/HXIAAOxyOalTbIJJ/80"/>
    <pic:link rel="preview" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/HXIAAOxyOalTbIJJ/81"/>
    <pic:link rel="big" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/HXIAAOxyOalTbIJJ/79"/>
    <pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/HXIAAOxyOalTbIJJ/78"/>
    <pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/HXIAAOxyOalTbIJJ/77"/></pic:picture>



<pic:picture><pic:link rel="extrabig" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/80AAAMXQeW5TbIJU/80"/>
<pic:link rel="preview" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/80AAAMXQeW5TbIJU/81"/>
<pic:link rel="big" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/80AAAMXQeW5TbIJU/79"/>
<pic:link rel="thumb" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/80AAAMXQeW5TbIJU/78"/>
<pic:link rel="moreadsthumb" href="http://akamai.hd.com/00/s/NzY4WDEwMjQ=/z/80AAAMXQeW5TbIJU/77"/>
</pic:picture></pic:pictures>
```

I've tried the following struct but it's not working

```
type Pictures Struct{
Pictures []Picture
}

type Picture struct {
    Rel  string `xml:"rel,attr"`
    Href string `xml:"href,attr"`
}
```

I see the element name is actually "link" but I don't know how to get that. The following doesn't seem to work either (i.e. I get no result/field)

```
    type Pictures struct{
    Pictures []Picture
    }

     type Link struct {
      Link []Link
      }
     type Link struct {
        Rel  string `xml:"rel,attr"`
        Href string `xml:"href,attr"`
    }
```

Comment: You can't have the XML package map to private (name starts with lower case char or `_`) fields. The reason is that the XML package can't see these fields since they are private to your package. Make them public and your code should work.

Comment: seems it's not working with upper case fields either. The question is corrected now

Comment: Now the only thing missing in your question is the XML you're trying to decode.

Comment: The XML was there but it was badly formatted . Updated now.

Comment: Your XML is broken? There's no closing tag for `<img:pictures>`. Also the namespace of the last closing tag is `pic` instead of what I suspect should be `img`

Comment: See [here](http://play.golang.org/p/KyZqMNGKUW) for a working example...

Comment: Indeed it seems the xml was not correct. However there is a bucket of pictures not only one picture so the working example is not working. I've updated it here http://play.golang.org/p/tWHzzun-s4

Comment: nevermind I fixed it http://play.golang.org/p/_I6FCYvaVn

Answer (score 0):

You basically have already written your decoder. The only thing that was missing were the element names "link" and "picture" I think. Here is a working example (I have just omitted the variable `input` containing your example from above:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    type Root struct {
        Pictures []struct {
            Links []struct {
                Rel  string `xml:"rel,attr"`
                Href string `xml:"href,attr"`
            } `xml:"link"`
        } `xml:"picture"`
    }

    var v Root
    err := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(input)).Decode(&v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    for _, pic := range v.Pictures {
        for _, link := range pic.Links {
            fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", link.Rel, link.Href)
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```